# Is there anyway to use custom worker node OS or load specific kernel modules in standard worker node OS on GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

GKE appears to support 3 type of worker-node OSs as of writing this question (around mid Aug'2021) i.e. Container optimized OS, Ubuntu, Windows. So my questions are:

- Is there a way (or a workaround) that lets one use RHEL as worker-node OS **on GKE** ?
- Is there a way (or a workaround) to load a kernel module (s.a. `modprobe sctp`) into worker-node OS **on GKE**, say while working with Ubuntu as the worker-node OS ?

Here the stress on **on GKE** is to emphasize that I'd like to use GKE as a managed CaaS service.

Comment: Not possible, You may need to work on Ubuntu instead.

Comment: @AlexG is there anyway to load SCTP module in the GKE Ubuntu worker-nodes ?